# Old puppet kids show about a hot air balloon going to another dimension

Tags: story-identification

Please help me, I’m writing this at 3:30am :(  I need peace of mind lol

I remember that there are 3 main characters, two boys and a girl. One of the boys is an apprentice to an old man building a hot air ballon and is told to not show others. But he ends up showing the girl he likes the hot air balloon to impress her. But as the girl rides it, lightning hits it and takes her to another dimension where an evil king locks her up in a dungeon. The boy then gets help from the other boy and go to the other dimension to try to save the girl.

After that I remember there being a part where the evil king finds one of the boys and is threatening to torture him on a device that pulls his arms and legs like a torture rack.

And another scene was when the evil king uses a device to mind control giants made of stones/boulders

And at the end they save the girl and repair the hot air balloon in time for a thunder storm so that lightning hits and they are able to go back to their world

I think its from the 90s and I remember watching it on either qubo or smile of a child. (I didn’t have cable so those where the only channels I watched for entertainment)

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is *Winds of Adventure!*, a segment on *[The World of Jonathan Singh](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/TheWorldOfJonathanSingh)* (fair warning, TV Tropes entry).

[image: Title image of The World of Jonathan Singh]

> This is the main segment of the series. The series starts with a teenager named Jarrod who has to rescue his friend Isabel from a group of nasty pirates. He and Professor Louie rescues her, but their hot air balloon gets zapped by lighting, which takes them into another world. The heroes meet the race of the new world, the tomarlings where they're being lead by Prince Rohanor. Their mission is take back the kingdom from King Halgor.

I believe the "transported to another world" bit starts at the end of Episode 3, leading into Episode 4, although the storyline is a bit different, with Isabella kidnapped by pirates.

Found with a search for `tv show "hot air balloon" lightning king puppets`